# Why are there multiple HTTP Methods available?

Tags: ajax, http, post, methods, get

Back when I first started developing client/server apps which needed to make use of HTTP to send data to the server, I was pretty nieve when it came to HTTP methods. I literally used GET requests for EVERYTHING.

I later learned that I should use POST for sending data and GET for requesting data however, I was slightly confused as to why this is best practice. From a functionality perspective, I was able to use either GET or POST to achieve the exact same thing.

Why is it important to use specific HTTP methods rather than using the same method for everything?

I understand that POST is more secure than GET (GET makes the data visible in the HTTP URL) however, couldn't we just use POST for everything then?

Comment: This post answers your questions https://medium.com/@suhas_chatekar/why-you-should-use-the-recommended-http-methods-in-your-rest-apis-981359828bf7

Comment: It's a good question, but the answer is a large essay!

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to take a stab at giving a short answer to this.

`GET` is used for reading information. It's the 'default' method, and everything uses this to jump from one link to the next. This includes browsers, but also crawlers.

`GET` is 'safe'. This means that if you do a `GET` request, you are guaranteed that you will never change something on the server. If a `GET` request could cause something to delete on the server, this can be very problematic because a spider/crawler/search engine might assume that following links is safe and automatically delete things.

This is why we have a couple of different methods. `GET` is meant to allow you to 'get' things from the server. Likewise, `PUT` allows you to set something new on a server and `DELETE` allows you remove something.

`POST`'s biggest original purpose is submitting forms. You're posting a form to the server and ask the server to do something with that form.

Any client (a human/browser or machine/crawler) knows that `POST` is 'unsafe'. It won't do `POST` requests automatically on your behalf unless it really knows it's what you (the user) wants. It's also used for things like are kinda similar to submitting forms.

So when you design your website, make sure you use `GET` only for getting things from the server, and use `POST` if your ajax request will cause 'something' to change on the server.

Fun fact: there are [a lot](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) of official HTTP methods. At least 30. You'll probably only use a very few of them though.

So to answer the question in the title more precisely:

> Why are there multiple HTTP Methods available?

Different HTTP methods have different rules and restrictions. If everyone agrees on those rules, we can start making assumptions about what the intent is. Because these guarantees exists, HTTP servers, clients and proxies can make smart decisions without understanding your specific application.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose, You have one task app in which you can store data, delete data. Now suppose the route of your web page is /xx so to get the webpage, to store the data using add button , to delete the data using delete button you will send requests to /xx but how web server will know whether you are asking for web page or you want to add data or you want to delete because /xx is the same for all requests that's why we have different web requests browser always sends request name(GET,POST,PUT,DELETE) in header to server so server can understand what you need.